# I have a 2 dimension array and I want to turn it on a 1d array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that process a SQL Select and returns an array, when I did a SELECT on my user types table, I received that array as return: 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [typ_cod] => ADM ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => CMM [typ_cod] => CMM ) )

Now I want to put it into a $options array, like this:
 Array([0] => ADM 
       [1] => CMM
      )

The first index of the returned array is the row number, and the second the colummns of the table. If anyone can help! Thanks!

Comment: So go ahead and do it.

Comment: I don't know how do to it...

Comment: What happened when you tried? This isn't a "do it for me" website.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple helper function

```
function getArrayValueList($RecordList, $RecordItemName)
{
    $Returnlist = array();
    foreach ($RecordList as $RecordIndex => $RecordItem) {
        $Returnlist[] = $RecordItem[$RecordItemName];
    }
    return array_unique($Returnlist);
}
```

and try

```
$array = array(array('typ_cod' => 'AMD'), array('typ_cod' => 'CMM'));
var_dump(getArrayValueList($array, 'typ_cod'));
```

Comment: Thanks uniq, you saved me! I will save this function for later use. It worked well!! Thanks for the knowledge!